# Laravel eloquent unconventional column not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Hi laravel is not inserting correct value in pivot table for many to many case.

Here my first model is

```
class ShippingAddress extends Eloquent {
  protected $guarded = array('id');
  protected $table = 'shippingAddress';

  public function mwsOrder()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('MwsOrder',
      'mwsOrders_shippingAddress',
      'Address_id',
      'AmazonOrderId'
    );
  }
}
```

Second Model is

```
class MwsOrder extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'mwsOrders';
  protected $primaryKey = 'AmazonOrderId';

  public function shippAddress()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('ShippingAddress',
        'mwsOrders_shippingAddress',
        'AmazonOrderId',
        'Address_id'
      );
   }

}
```

EER Diagram [image]

Now when i run this

```
$mwsOrder = new MwsOrder;
$mwsOrder->AmazonOrderId = 'Eve 6';
$mwsOrder->save();

$address = new ShippingAddress;
$address->name = 'Naruto Uzumaki';
$address->save();
$address->mwsOrder()->attach($mwsOrder);
//$mwsOrder->shippAddress()->save($address);
```

laravel throws error and this is what laravel trying to run the query

> (SQL: insert into `mwsOrders_shippingAddress` (`Address_id`,
>   `AmazonOrderId`) values (1, 3))

What i need is to generate this query

> insert into `mwsOrders_shippingAddress` (`Address_id`,
>   `AmazonOrderId`) values (1, 'Eve 6')

Update: 
Schema are:

```
Schema::create("shippingAddress", function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments("id");
  $table->string("Name");
  $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create("mwsOrders", function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments("id");
  $table->string("AmazonOrderId")->unique();
  $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create("mwsOrders_shippingAddress", function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments("id");
  $table->string("AmazonOrderId");
  $table->foreign("AmazonOrderId")->references("AmazonOrderId")->on('mwsOrders');
  $table->integer("shipping_address_id")->unsigned();
  $table->foreign("shipping_address_id")->references('id')->on('shippingAddress');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the order of local and foreign key be flipped around 
public function shippAddress()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('ShippingAddress',
      'mwsOrders_shippingAddress',
      'AmazonOrderId',AmazonOrderId
      'Address_id'

    );
  }

Comment: i intentionally changed it, i tried all four combination of changing coloumns but still laravel is picking the id field instead of "AmazonOrderId"

Answer (score 1):

At first change the `shippAddress` to this:

```
// Specify the primary key because it's not conventional id
protected $primaryKey = 'AmazonOrderId';

public function shippAddress()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ShippingAddress',
        'mwsOrders_shippingAddress',
        'AmazonOrderId',
        'Address_id'
    );
}
```

Then you may try this:

```
$mwsOrder = new MwsOrder;
$mwsOrder->AmazonOrderId = 'Eve 6';
$mwsOrder->save();

$address = new ShippingAddress(['name' => 'Naruto Uzumaki']);
$mwsOrder->shippAddress()->save($address); // Save and Attach
```

Comment: at first i used "AmazonOrderId" before "Adress_id" but it still not wokring it is grabbing the actual id coloumn instead of "AmazonOrderId" from table "MwsOrder"

Comment: sounds like the solution is right to me, i am moving to version 5 will update you soon when it's done, thanks

Comment: No, It's Not working. But it should do work because i have gone through Model filed and getKey() is getting attribute based on $primaryKey which by default is set to id. So i introduced protected $primaryKey as you mentioned it still returning the value from id. Strange :(

Comment: attached schema too in original question